# Can QGIS save a raster as best-fit off axis rectangle

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, world-file

I often have rasters from real world data collected along straight-ish routes that can largely be in any heading, eg 45 degrees, 160 degrees etc.

The standard raster saving operation will pad this out with null data such that it very inefficiently goes from xmin, ymin to xmax, ymax, and my data will only form a stripe with <10% of the full bounds containing valid data.

Is there any standard function or plug in that can work out a best fit rectangle along the orientation of my data and save it like that.

The TIFF worldfile should allow for an off horizontal orientation and still allow the data to be correctly georeferenced.

Comment: You'd be solving one problem (efficiency of managing rasters with large areas of nulls) by creating a bigger problem (needing a custom projection for each raster based on orientation).

Comment: Surely it could stay at the same rotation?  The world file has rotation coeffiecients, so it would still be possible to have a grid whose coordinates were still easily mapped to the correct point.

Comment: What projection(s) are you expecting this data to be used with?

Comment: UTM30 or 31N usually.  I have data in corridors that are 100s of metres wide, but km to tens of km long.

Comment: You can create a world file with rotation. However, if the data is saved as GeoTIFF, the world file then gets ignored. So you need to strip the projection data, load the plain TIFF (with world file), and then manually assign the projection. What format is your data in before it is loaded into QGIS? You might be able to do something with a custom GDAL command line.

Comment: Sorry I was off a few days.  My data usually comes in a simple ASCII xyz that I can rasterise any way I fancy.  However geotiff seems to work best for the range of other packages different departments use for their various projects.

Comment: Might be worthwhile providing a link to a sample raster in the question (if it's not sensitive). Someone can do some testing with a real-world example to see if there's a solution.